# Display a ‘loading’ image while a time consuming function is executed in Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, flask

I have an app in Flask that looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def start():
    return render_template('page1.html')  # loads the start page on the beginning

@app.route('/page2',methods=['GET','POST'])
def read():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # lots of actions taking a long time
        return render_template('page2.html', arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)
```

I want to add a photo on my HTML page that will show "loading" until page2 will upload. This is similar to my current HTML on page1:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IP / ISP Research</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="/static/style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <h2>Search for something</h2>
<form class="form-style-7" action="/page2" method="POST" >
    <ul>
    <li>
        <label for="arg1">IP</label>
        <input type="text" name="arg1" value="{{arg1}}" maxlength="100">
        <span>Enter arg1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="arg2">ISP</label>
        <input type="text" name="arg2" value="{{arg2}}" maxlength="100">
        <span>Enter arg2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="go_button" type="submit" value="GO" >
    </li>
    </ul>
</form>    
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Things I've tried:

Mostly writing javascripts in my HTML such as shown [here](http://www.netavatar.co.in/2011/05/31/how-to-show-a-loading-gif-image-while-a-page-loads-using-javascript-and-css/).

Also tried adding a function for `showImage()` and adding this to the HTML form tag: `onclick="showImage()`

Also tried adding this to the HTML button tag: `onSubmit="return showImage()`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery for example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IP / ISP Research</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="/static/style.css"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <h2>Search for something</h2>
<form class="form-style-7" action="/page2" method="POST" >
    <ul>
    <li>
        <label for="arg1">IP</label>
        <input type="text" name="arg1" value="{{arg1}}" maxlength="100">
        <span>Enter arg1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="arg2">ISP</label>
        <input type="text" name="arg2" value="{{arg2}}" maxlength="100">
        <span>Enter arg2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="go_button" type="submit" value="GO" >
    </li>
    </ul>
</form>    
<script>
    $( ".go_button" ).submit(function( event ) {
        # function showing loading progress bar
    });
</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, i'm not familiar with javascript or jQuery, can you please help with the full function that I need to write? and do I put it in my HTML <head>?